# how to combine two android projects with a another screen

Tags: android, android-intent, merge

i have two android projects 
 1. **android 1**
 2. **android 2**
I want to design another project with two buttons. When i click 1st button it will start android 2, and when i press 2nd button it will start android 2.
I want all these project as one Executable file.

Answer (score 0):

Setup android 1 and android 2 as library projects

once that is done, you will have to copy all activity definitions (as well as services, recievers, etc) that you want to use to your client project to the client manifest file.

then in your onClickListener, you can use the regular startActivity/startActivityForResult methods

see [this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html) for a tutorial on library projects